# Get width and height of an iframe with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an iframe on a page. For this example, its height is 0px and width is 100px.

I want to console.log these values with JavaScript.

At the moment I can access the `iframe` using `window.frames[0]`, but how do I then get the width and height? What I'm doing currently returns `undefined`.

Here is the code and Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/prvmwg5q/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
<style>
</style>
<script src=""></script>
<body>

<iframe data-search-id="mainline-top" style="height: 0px; width: 100px;">
Test
</iframe>

<script>

console.log(window.frames[0]);

console.log(window.frames[0].offsetHeight); // Undefined
console.log(window.frames[0].offsetWidth); // Undefined

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might try `window.frames[0].innerHeight` and `window.frames[0].innerWidth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.frames` does not return the DOM element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames

Instead, give your `iframe` an `id` and use `getElementById` instead.

EDIT: Or, better, as @HereticMonkey points out:

`document.querySelector('iframe')`

Comment: Interesting didn't know that. The iframe on my website comes from a different origin so I can't set its id. However, it has a data attribute. Can the DOM element of the iframe be accessed with this data attribute? I edited my question to reflect this

Comment: Or just use `document.querySelector('iframe')`. No need to give every element an id...

Comment: Good call @HereticMonkey! Updated my answer. @Albert I think that should do what you need without the data attribute :)